# best way to call function (again and again)

Tags: sql, function, call

I have a large table (1 mio rows) and have this query:

```
Select ...,
 case
   when datediff(day,getdate())<30 then 'Month'
   when datediff(day,getdate())<90 then 'Quater"
   when datediff(day,getdate())<365 then 'YEAR'
   else  'OLD'  END
....
```

how do I prevent it from executing the function three times for each old row..??

I would love something like

```
case datediff(day,getdate())
when between 0 and 30 then 'month'
when between 31 and 90 then...
```

Comment: Are you sure that the datediff()-function will be repeated `n` times? The optimizer should be smart enough to see this afaik.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the datediff()-function will be repeated n times? The optimizer should be smart enough to see this afaik.

Besides that what you can always do is to calculate `datediff` for every row in a query and apply the `case` in an outer query.

```
select ..., case when a.my_diff ..., ... from (
    select ..., datediff(...) as 'my_diff', ... from ...
) a
```

Comment: I have pulled in your comment because it makes the answer complete. Hope you are OK with that.